# lock mutliple text box on a button click in mvc3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have made a form with multiple text boxes. On submit button click I want text boxes in the form to be locked as to prevent any editing of the shown data.

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449508/asp-net-mvc-disabled-text-box-updated-by-javascript-does-not-post-new-value

may this link will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
      $("input").attr("disabled", true);
      return true;
    });
  });
</script>
```