# textBox.text is empty in onClick function Server side

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a very simple asp.net page and something not working as it should be.

**This is the structure of my page:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Management/page.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Account.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div class="contentWrapper">
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="MainPanel" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="MainPanel" OnLoad="MainPanel_Load">
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
                <asp:Panel  runat="server" id="PasswordHolder" CssClass="rtl" Width="100%" ClientIDMode="Static">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="PasswordInput" CssClass="block" TextMode="Password" />
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="btn ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" ID="EditBtn" OnClick="EditBtn_Click"><span class="ui-button-text">submit</span></asp:LinkButton>
                </asp:Panel>
        </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Now: I'm entering a text in the TextBox(PasswordInput) and clicking submit.

The Server catch the event and entering EditBtn_Click function.

BUT! PasswordInput.Text is empty.

What should I do to fix that?

**Server Side Code:**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentUser() == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx", true);
        }
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ViewState["ContactsSortExpression"] = "LastName";
            ViewState["ContactsSortDirection"] = "ASC";
        }

    }
protected void EditBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PasswordInput.Text == currentUser().Password)
        {
                //Do something
        }
     }
```

Comment: I guess you should use FindControl to find PasswordInput inside  panels hierarchy.

Comment: FindControl didn't find any control in my page. all the returns was null

Comment: How do you use FindControl method, can you provide that code too?

Comment: FindControl("ControlName") - or maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: I tested the code you provided and it worked as expected, the problem may be somewhere else in your code. Maybe an unintended assignment or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Problem was the Jquery dialog function**

For an answer look here:
[asp.net Textbox value is null when post bock with Jquery Dialog occured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527753/asp-net-textbox-value-is-null-when-post-bock-with-jquery-dialog-occured)