# textbox from popup modal always return empty

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

i need explanation about my problem... "textbox from popup modal always return empty" when i clicked the save button from popup modal.. i need to get the value of the txtCityName.Text and the txtCityDescription.Text;

```
here's my code... 
======================
THE HTML
=======================
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="modal.aspx.cs" Inherits="sample.modal" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="DivModifyCity" runat="server" class="modal" style="overflow: hidden; margin-top: 50px; display: none">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <div style="display: inline-block;" class="pull-right ">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCloseCity" runat="server" CssClass="icon-remove" ToolTip="Close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" type="button" value="Close" Height="20px"></asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
                <h3>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCityStatus" runat="server" Text="Add City"></asp:Label></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="input-medium" style="width: 140px">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="input-medium" style="width: 140px">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="City Name" Font-Size="12pt"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCityName" type="text" placeholder="City Name" runat="server" MaxLength="150"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="input-medium" style="width: 140px">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="input-medium" style="width: 140px">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="City Description" Font-Size="12pt"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCityDescription" type="text" runat="server" placeholder="Description" Height="50px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSaveCity" runat="server" Font-Underline="false" Font-Bold="true" Text="Save" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Height="20px" ToolTip="Add new city" OnClick="btnSaveCity_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#DivModifyCity" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch demo modal</a>
    </form>

    <%--    modal popup--%>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../Scripts/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>

    <%-- end here--%>
</body>
</html>

=========================
server side code:
=========================
 protected void btnSaveCity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string try1 = txtCityName.Text;
            string try2 = txtCityDescription.Text;
        }
```

Comment: Is this something like:[asp.net Textbox value is null when post bock with Jquery Dialog occured](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18527753/690329)?

Comment: @afzalulh = if you try to changed the style of the div display from "none" to "block" its working fine...

Comment: Please help me to solve this issue its urgent please...

Comment: All I can see the control name is wrong:`string try1 = txtCityName.Text;` should be `string try1 = txtCityNames.Text;`. Otherwise, your code is fine!

Comment: @afzalulh - you can try my code above.

Comment: I have tried your code.

Comment: yes i've try it already but it always return empty text

Comment: Hi afzalulh, have you tried my code please post ur solution here please

Comment: any suggestion please

Comment: You can download the project I have used to test: I have used your code without any issue. The link is [Here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6i8p65gmkp0NmF0ZXlhVjR3LWM/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: @afzalulh i would like to know the changes that u made in my code....

Comment: Can you put the explanation about it? please i need to know why..

Comment: As I said, I just have used your code and I think they are fine. From the beginning I am telling you that your code is working. Only thing I can think of, `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap-modal.js` references may be missing those files in your project?